# JSLint is suddenly reporting: Use the function form of "use strict"

Tags: javascript, jslint

I include the statement:

```
"use strict";
```

at the beginning of most of my Javascript files.

JSLint has never before warned about this. But now it is, saying:

> Use the function form of "use strict".

Does anyone know what the "function form" would be?

Answer (score 1047, accepted):

Include `'use strict';` as the first statement in a wrapping function, so it only affects that function.  This prevents problems when concatenating scripts that aren't strict.

See Douglas Crockford's latest blog post [Strict Mode Is Coming To Town](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/12/14/strict-mode-is-coming-to-town/).

Example from that post:

```
(function () {
   'use strict';
   // this function is strict...
}());

(function () {
   // but this function is sloppy...
}());
```

**Update:**
In case you don't want to wrap in immediate function (e.g. it is a node module), then you can disable the warning.

For **JSLint** (per [Zhami](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11375064/2688)):

```
/*jslint node: true */
```

For **JSHint**:

```
/*jshint strict:false */
```

or (per [Laith Shadeed](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/4462560/revisions))

```
/* jshint -W097 */
```

To disable any arbitrary warning from JSHint, check the map in [JSHint source code](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/master/src/messages.js) (details in [docs](http://www.jshint.com/docs/)).

**Update 2:** **JSHint** supports `node:boolean` option. See [`.jshintrc` at github](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/4c2d091b7e50ce2681ee48a104578bb969c189ae/examples/.jshintrc#L79).

```
/* jshint node: true */
```

Comment: In JSLint for Visual Studio it's the option: "Allow global ES5 strict"

Comment: This doesn't make sense for Node applications, though. `-1`

Comment: Hi Nico, I updated the answer, for node you can type: /* jshint -W097 */ to disable this warning

Comment: @LaithShadeed An alternative would be `/*jshint strict:false */`, to make it clearer what you're doing (unless there's a particular benefit to your numeric code that I'm not aware of)

Comment: You are right and also globalstrict: true, http://www.jshint.com/docs/options/#globalstrict, but i did not check jshint source code to confirm if all of them will end up with same result.

Comment: @KulbirSaini have you tested your change?  From my quick testing, if you've configured JSHint to warn when you're missing `"use strict"` (because it doesn't warn by default), then setting the `node` option to `true` doesn't turn that warning off

Comment: @bdukes here is what I have. Jshint v2.8.0 (via `grunt-contrib-jshint`). It warns about `'use strict'` by default. Setting `"globalstrcit": true` in .jshintrc or via `Gruntfile.js` suppresses that warning. Alternate way to suppress the warning is setting `"node": true`. But yes, I do get warning by default.

Also `globalstrict` is set to `false` in example `.jshintrc` (https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/4c2d091b7e50ce2681ee48a104578bb969c189ae/examples/.jshintrc#L53) which I guess reflects the default behavior.

Comment: So every single function I ever write in Javascript is supposed to have this line of boilerplate?

Comment: @Noumenon it's not really boilerplate, it's a directive that changes the environment your code is running in.  That said, the new ES6 syntax (modules and classes) are strict by default (see http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-strict-mode-code), so going forward this won't need to be littered everywhere.  In the meantime, you can wrap all of your code in an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) to only have to specify `"use strict";` once per file.

Comment: I don't think writing IIFE around all files in a modern JS project is always a good practice. Of course, the isolation of your components is important, but writing it in the source code add extra-work, expose you to the possibility that one of the coders forget it sometimes, and don't help reading it. You won't need it anymore if you're correctly using your grunt / gulp to automatically add it at "build time". In my case, I switched to eslint, and I simply used ``"strict": [2, "global"]``

Comment: Also, `/*jshint browserify: true */` will achieve the same effect, and should be used if browserify is used. Browserify, like nodejs wraps the file inside an IIFE.

Answer (score 221):

If you're writing modules for NodeJS, they are already encapsulated. Tell JSLint that you've got node by including at the top of your file:

```
/*jslint node: true */
```

Comment: FYI, this option works for JSLint, but JSHint doesn't turn off the strictness warning with this directive.  For JSHint, try `/*jshint strict:false */`

Comment: Worded for me with JSHint v2.9.2. Added `"node": true` to .jshintrc

Answer (score 72):

I'd suggest to use [jshint](https://github.com/jshint/jshint) instead.

It allows to suppress this warning via `/*jshint globalstrict: true*/`.

If you are writing a library, I would only suggest using global strict if your code is encapsulated into modules as is the case with nodejs.

Otherwise you'd force everyone who is using your library into strict mode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6803305/should-i-use-jslint-or-jshint-javascript-validation

Comment: FYI: The globalstrict option in JSHint has changed. Try `strict: 'global'` now, and see http://jshint.com/docs/options/#globalstrict

Answer (score 19):

I started creating a Node.js/browserify application following the [Cross Platform JavaScript](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/02/cross-platform-javascript/) blog post. And I ran into this issue, because my brand new Gruntfile didn't pass jshint.

Luckily I found an answer in the [Leanpub book on Grunt](https://leanpub.com/grunt/read):

> If we try it now, we will scan our Gruntfile… and get some errors:
>
> ```
> $ grunt jshint
>
> Running "jshint:all" (jshint) task
> Linting Gruntfile.js...ERROR
> [L1:C1] W097: Use the function form of "use strict".
> 'use strict';
> Linting Gruntfile.js...ERROR
> [L3:C1] W117: 'module' is not defined.
> module.exports = function (grunt) {
>
> Warning: Task "jshint:all" failed. Use --force to continue.
> ```
>
> Both errors are because the Gruntfile is a Node program, and by default JSHint does not recognise or allow the use of `module` and the string version of `use strict`. We can set a JSHint rule that will accept our Node programs. Let’s edit our jshint task configuration and add an options key:
>
> ```
> jshint: {
>   options: {
>     node: true
>   },
> }
> ```

Adding `node: true` to the jshint `options`, to put jshint into "Node mode", removed both errors for me.

Answer (score 18):

Add a file .jslintrc (or .jshintrc in the case of jshint) at the root of your project with the following content:

```
{
    "node": true
}
```

Answer (score 17):

There's nothing innately wrong with the string form.

Rather than avoid the "global" strict form for worry of concatenating non-strict javascript, it's probably better to just fix the damn non-strict javascript to be strict.

Answer (score 2):

```
process.on('warning', function(e) {
    'use strict';
    console.warn(e.stack);
});
process.on('uncaughtException', function(e) {
    'use strict';
    console.warn(e.stack);
});
```

add this lines to at the starting point of your file

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone missed the "suddenly" part of this question.  Most likely, your .jshintrc has a syntax error, so it's not including the 'browser' line.  Run it through a json validator to see where the error is.

Comment: No, it suddenly happened because the online JSLint service added that feature in 2010 when the question was asked.

Answer (score -4):

This is how simple it is: If you want to be strict with all your code, add `"use strict";` at the start of your JavaScript.

But if you only want to be  strict with some of your code, use the function form. Anyhow, I would recomend you to use it at the beginning of your JavaScript because this will help you be a better coder.

Comment: I actually do get this error when I only put `"use strict";` at the top of my JS file, so this might not be entirely true.

Comment: @moesef That is because you have errors in your code. It's just there to help make your coding skills better better and make your code less "loose"... it will not accept undeclared variables etc...

Comment: @JasonStackhouse: Not true. JSLint won't accept the "global" form of `"use strict";`, where it's just placed at the top of your code. It only allows `"use strict;"` when wrapped in a function. (JS_Hint_ allows you to use the global form, though -- see answer above for the setting needed).