# jshint "use strict" issue

Tags: jshint

Here's my file: `app/scripts/controllers/main.js`

```
"use strict";

angular.module('appApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  }]);
```

My `Gruntfile.coffee` has:

```
jshint:
    options:
        globals:
            require: false
            module: false
            console: false
            __dirname: false
            process: false
            exports: false

    server:
        options:
            node: true
        src: ["server/**/*.js"]

    app:
        options:
            globals:
                angular: true
                strict: true

        src: ["app/scripts/**/*.js"]
```

When I run `grunt`, I get:

```
Linting app/scripts/controllers/main.js ...ERROR
[L1:C1] W097: Use the function form of "use strict".
"use strict";
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The issue is that if you don't use the function form it applies to everything, and not just your code. The solution to that is to scope `use strict` inside functions you control.

Refer to this question: [JSLint is suddenly reporting: Use the function form of “use strict”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4462478/389745).

Rather than doing

```
"use strict";

angular.module('appApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  }]);
```

You should be doing

```
angular.module('appApp')
  .controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    "use strict";

    $scope.awesomeThings = [
      'HTML5 Boilerplate',
      'AngularJS',
      'Karma'
    ];
  }]);
```

It's either that or wrapping your code in a self-executing closure, like below.

```
(function(){
    "use strict";

    // your stuff
})();
```

Comment: It is actually the right way to do it, but how do I tell jshint to just ignore the warning? I have a bunch of .js files that work and I don't want to edit each and every on of them.

Comment: You should, because you could be breaking external libraries if you don't.

Comment: `it applies to everything, and not just your code` - only if you're concatenating your script with others. Otherwise it only applies to your code.

Answer (score 8):

Changed my `Gruntfile.coffee` to include `globalstrict`

```
jshint:
    options:
        globalstrict: true
        globals:
            require: false
            module: false
            console: false
            __dirname: false
            process: false
            exports: false
```

Comment: "This option suppresses warnings about the use of global strict mode."  Sounds like a band-aid rather than a solution.

Comment: It's been a number of years.  I can see projects requiring "get strict or get out" of their dependencies.