# "Use the function form of "use strict" when using Gulp + Babel + JsHint

Tags: javascript, gulp, jshint, babeljs

I get this warning:

```
"Use the function form of "use strict"
```

when gulp watch my js files.

How to solve this?
I´m using gulp, gulp-babel and gulp-jshint.

Code ex:

```
.pipe( babel() )
.pipe( jshint( ".jshintrc" ) )
```

I´m not writting the `'use strict'` on my code. It was generated by babel.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462478/jslint-is-suddenly-reporting-use-the-function-form-of-use-strict

Comment: Just don't use jshint. Or rather, pipe it *before* your `babel()`. You should lint your ES6 code, not something that a transpiler produces.

Comment: gulp-jshint works on all ES6 specs?

Comment: @Patric: I don't know that - try it. If not, check the docs (possibly it needs a flag) and maybe a) file it as a bug report b) use a different linter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To reiterate what Bergi said in the comments, you shouldn't be linting code that you didn't write. You should switch the order and run jshint *before* using babel.