# Is there something wrong if I use or not "use strict" mode in JS?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Gulp file and I just set JSHint, I see this option in the `.jshintrc` file:

> "strict" : true

then I went to my files I put this at the very beginning:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {. . .});
```

and I now I am getting a new error

> public/app.js
>     line 1  col 1  Use the function form of "use strict".

so I did:

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(function($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {

  'use strict';

   return { . . . }

});
```

and the error its gone.

So, what is the difference here and what is wrong if I don't use the strict mode?

Comment: See [What does “use strict” do in JavaScript, and what is the reasoning behind it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1335851/1529630) and [JSLint is suddenly reporting: Use the function form of “use strict”](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4462478/1529630)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSHint by default doesn't allow you to have `'use strict';` at a global scope when set to true, because it will interfere with Javascript libraries and legacy code that isn't designed for strict mode in mind.

Use

> strict: 'global'

if you want to be able to do that.

or

> strict: false

if you do not want to lint code to require strict mode.

---

[strict option reference for JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#strict)

Comment: Oh, I see. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode  This tells you how strict mode behaves